# FullSimplify applied to equations: not simplifying though apparently it should

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I tried to `Fullsimplify` 
$$ e^x(1-x)=0$$
to the equation
$$1-x=0$$ 
However the command

```
 FullSimplify[E^x (1 - x) == 0]
```

just gives
$$e^x x = e^x $$
Probably this does not matter for the specific equation. But in general it can cause a great loss of time.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[E^x (1 - x) == 0, Element[x, Reals]]
```

> x == 1

And, strangely enough,

```
FullSimplify[E^x (1 - x) == 0, whattheheck]
```

> x == 1

Also

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], FullSimplify[E^x (1 - x) == 0]]
```

> x == 1

```
Reduce[E^x (1 - x) == 0, x]
```

> x == 1

```
FullSimplify[E^x (1 - x) == 0, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Reduce}]
```

> x == 1

Comment: What's the best way to state that $x\in(0,+\infty)$ in the beggining of my notebook?

Comment: @user61386, `$Assumptions =x>0`?

Comment: `$Assumptions = {x>0}` lol

Comment: And what if I need to do this for more than one variable, say state that $x\in(0,+\infty)$, $z\in(0,1)$  etc. ?

Comment: @user61386, `$Assumptions = {x>0, 0<z<1}`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Simplify[E^x (1 - x) == 0, E^x != 0]
```

This tells Mathematica that it can assume that `E^x` is not zero.

Comment: Of course this works. However   this trick is unpractical for more complicated equations.  How could I make mathematica recognise the  fact that $e^x>0$, $\cosh x >0$, etc. avoiding lengthy commands that state explicitly what seems profound?

Comment: Telling it that `Element[x,Reals]` would be sufficient in that case. As mathematica will figure out that this implies that `E^x >0` etc. However, in some more complicated cases (for example involving square roots) you may need to give it assumptions about more complicated expressions.